# NestedScrollView not scrolling

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-design-library, android-appbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

Ok so I have a global CoordinatorLayout with the following layout

[image: app_bar_main.xml]

content_main is a FrameLayout that fragments are transacted into. For this particular fragment I have a requirement of placing a TabLayout at a certain % of screenheight, so I went the route of using a ViewPager (with each fragment containing a NestedScrollView to coordinate with the CoordinatorLayout for proper scrolling behavior -- which all works as expected). However my transacted fragment layout (NestedScrollView) is not scrolling at all, however the layout_behavior is working as the AppBar/ToolBar are reacting to a scroll.

[image: fragment_feature.xml]

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have created a sample project to show current broken behavior. https://github.com/bmc08gt/NestedScrollView-with-ViewPager The intended behavior is for the tablayout to collapse to the toolbar.

Comment: Are you saying you have nested fragments?

Comment: CoordinatorLayout contains the fragment that is transacted into the FrameLayout. Said Fragment contains content and a viewpager (at required height %) that holds 3 fragments(one per tab).